# How to use Comet and Push technique using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, push, comet

I am calling an AJAX after each 5 seconds to update the some info of current logged-in user into database table in PHP.

But it creates a heavy load on my website, and website down after some time when there are multiple users logged-in on my website.

Is there any way to use some other techniques like Comet or Push to improve my script?

Here is a code i am using:

**Javascript code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   

   update_data(); 

   function update_data() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "$URL",
       data: {update_current_time:1},
       success: function(response){
         setTimeout(update_data, 5000);
       },
       error: function(){
         setTimeout(update_data, 5000);
       }
     });
   }
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['update_current_time']))
{
   $query = "UPDATE users SET user_timer=now() WHERE  user_id=".$_SESSION['id'];
   $db->execute();
   echo 'success';
   die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use push or comet you will need to setup up a "webserver" that will listen to some port. So this cannot be solved using pure php but needs a listener setup (unless you create your on listening server using php).

To stay at php you can check out [ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/).

Another common way to go would be a node.js server parrallel to your webserver.

Comment: I did't find any useful material from google, so that i have posted it on stackoverflow. If you know some useful articles, please share it.

Comment: there wont be any article covering your usecase. you will have to search for information and understand sockets. i linked ratchet library - there is some basic information. for anything specific you have to dig deeper yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I ever encounter this use case, My Implementation would be using the session variable. Instead of writing to database every 5 seconds, I'd store the request timestamps in $_SESSION for like 1-2 Minutes, and then write the whole data at once. For this example lets consider that you wish to make it a minute(60 sec).

So the algorithm would be

1. Make the request from client side.
2. On the server check if the session variable `$_SESSION['requestcount']` is set.
3. If its not set, then I shall set that variable to 1, also I'll store the timestamp in some sub-array and return `status 200 OK`.
4. If its set I'll check if the value for `$_SESSION['requestcount']` is 12 (*1 request every 5 seconds x 12*).
5. If the value of `$_SESSION['requestcount']` is less than 12 then I'll increment its value by 1 and return `status 200 OK`.
6. If the value of `$_SESSION['requestcount']` is equal to or grater than 12 then I'll Get all data from the sub-array and prepare it to insert inside the database, Also reset the `$_SESSION['requestcount']` to 0, if all is well return `status 200 OK`.

Comment: How about if user left the browser before writing the data from session created by you?

Comment: Then you miss only the amount of log(*or whatever you call it*) within the last interval.

Comment: Other option would be to use **memcached** or some sort of store in memory(RAM) thingy. But it should be provided by your webhost though.